# Tomcat datasource Properties with Docker and Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, docker

Trying to figure out the best way to configure JNDI lookups within a Tomcat container provisioned with docker.

So far I've come up with:

**Storing the context.xml somewhere secure on the target servers then referencing them within the Dockerfile**

Problems with this:

- Removes portability

This defeats the purpose of docker in that it removes the "configure once, deploy anywhere" mentality that docker stands by. Each developer would need the context.xml stored locally on their machine in order to make it work

**Add a build-step to echo out jenkins maintained credentials to a file, then bind it with docker-compose env.file which is loaded by the app via properties (do not use JNDI lookups).**

- This is a slightly better solution that is maintainable at the Jenkins and developer level.  The developer would just have to make sure to either update the properties themselves, or provide their own properties locally.

**Externally host credentials**

Use something like zookeeper, or redis to provide runtime key-values to lookup database credentials.

Not sure what the standard is at the moment, and online resources seem to be all over the place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the way around this would be to use an external configuration source such as zookeeper, or Archaius.

This is outside the scope of both Docker and Jenkins control and is purely an application problem.